# moving a gif image right

Tags: html, css, tumblr

Ive been using simple html and css to make my new webpage. its just a gradient background with a gif in front of it. the gif has been giving me a lot of grief lately because it keeps moving out of to the right and extending the scree. i just want the gif to be centered perfectedly and at a good size right not the desktop version looks ideal but the mobile version looks so small as seen below I would just like the gif to be wider and feel the screen more without extending it. [image]

[image]

my HTML goes as following

```css
  a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Custom default button */

.btn-default,
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritence from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


/*
     * Base structure
     */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  background: radial-gradient( circle closest-side, #d5c83d 80%, #e9e5bf, #8482e3);
}


/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */

.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100%; */
  min-height: 100%;
}

.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* Padding for spacing */

.inner {
  padding: 20px;
}


/*
     * Header
     */

.masthead-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.masthead-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.masthead-nav>li+li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.masthead-nav>li>a {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  /* IE8 proofing */
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.masthead-nav>li>a:hover,
.masthead-nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.masthead-nav>.active>a,
.masthead-nav>.active>a:hover,
.masthead-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .masthead-nav {
    float: right;
  }
  .jumbotron {
    padding-top: calc(var(--jumbotron-padding-y) * 2);
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--jumbotron-padding-y) * 2);
  }
}


/*
     * Cover
     */

.cover {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*
     * Affix and center
     */

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="site-wrapper">

  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="container inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand"></h3>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="">Home*</a></li>
              <li><a href="magazine">Magazine#</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Abouti</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="innercover">

        <img class="img" src="https://static.tumblr.com/y8b11bc/u05qfybi7/ezgif.com-resize.gif" ; style=" top: 0%; width: 100%; max-height: 100%; " ;></img>
      </div>
```

Comment: you want gif to be center in yellow grident or center of the page?

Comment: @deepak id like it to be in the cente of the yellow circle

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your css code to change the size of the GIF depending if it's mobile or desktop. Also, adjust the div that holds the GIF to center the items.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .img{
      width: X%
     }
    .innercover{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
     }
```